# Index documentation url with ELK stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I want to load below documentation using logstash to do indexing it with elastic search:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.common.doc/doc/t0020018.html

Currently,I am able to index all the logs with elasticsearch,but I am not sure how to index documentation with a url.

Is this scenario is valid with logstash,if yes,please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give it a go by using the [http poller](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http_poller.html#plugins-inputs-http_poller) plugin which was [released](https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-logstash-http-poller) recently, within your *logstash* config itself. The `input` could look something like this:

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      myurl=> "https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.common.doc/doc/t0020018.html"
      }
    }
    request_timeout => 60
    interval => 60
    codec => "json"  <--- to decode the results to json
  }
}
```

The above is just a sample so that you could reproduce. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the information,it seems working,but how to load all data if I give the master url link,so that it will load all the sublinks/topics of the given url,suppose if i give https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.kc.doc/welcome.html

,it will load all the topics of this product also...

Comment: @AkshayAnand I don't think it'll automatically pick up all the sub urls from the master url. You may have to use multiple urls within the **urls** property.

Comment: i was thinking the same,but its better to include some logic for picking up all the sublinks also...